# how to store images from server(api) to room database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, android-glide

I want to store images from and api into room db.I receive data and images from an api. When I'm in online mode, the images are loaded using the urls provided by the api but when offline, images should be stored and retrieved from the database in offline mode.

im loading the images like this (it loads images):----

```
 if (!data.data.images.isNullOrEmpty()) {

            val base = BuildConfig.SERVER_URL.replace("api/", "")

            data.data.images.forEachIndexed { pos, it ->

                Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(base + it?.imagePath)
                    .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        override fun onResourceReady(
                                resource: Bitmap,
                                transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                        ) {
                            imageClick = pos + 1
                            val file = File(
                                    getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                    "${System.currentTimeMillis()}${Constants.PROFILE_PIC_FILE_EXTENSION}"
                            )
                            imagePath = file.absolutePath
                            Utils.saveBitmapToFile(resource, imagePath)
                            Utils.compressImage(imagePath)
                            onCropImageResult(resource)
                        }

                        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                        }
                    })
                     }
                     }
```

my JSON is like this:--------

```
 "data" : {
  .
  .
  .
"images" : [ {
  "assetImageId" : 4113,
  "transactionTypeId" : 2,
  "transactionId" : 88341,
  "imageURL" : "",
  "imagePath" : "UserData/AssetImages/INS-0000017673_1616058387618.jpg",
  "createdBy" : 0,
  "createdOn" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "updatedBy" : null,
  "updatedOn" : null,
  "isActive" : 0,
  "isNew" : false,
  "isDeleted" : false,
  "isChanged" : false,
  "timestamp" : null
}, {
  "assetImageId" : 4114,
  "transactionTypeId" : 2,
  "transactionId" : 88341,
  "imageURL" : "",
  "imagePath" : "UserData/AssetImages/INS-0000017673_1616058402212.jpg",
  "createdBy" : 0,
  "createdOn" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "updatedBy" : null,
  "updatedOn" : null,
  "isActive" : 0,
  "isNew" : false,
  "isDeleted" : false,
  "isChanged" : false,
  "timestamp" : null
} ],
 }
```

my entity table :---

```
@Entity(tableName = DatabaseConstants.MYTABLE, indices = [Index(value = ["requestId"], unique = true)])
  data class AllocationDetailsByIdEntity(
    var requestId: String? = null,
    var subLocation: String? = null,
    var amsTagId: String? = null,
    var status: String? = null,
    var installedBy: String? = null,
    var installedDate: String? = null,
    val assetTree: String? = null,
    var images: List<ImagesssItem?>? =null,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int? = null
   ): Serializable

   @Entity
 data class ImagesssItem (
var assetImageId :String?= null,
var transactionTypeId: Int? = null,
var transactionId: Int? = null,
var imageURL: String? = null,
var imagePath: String? = null
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id : Int? = null

 ):Serializable
```

tried solution 1:--this is not working

```
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
```

Any idea how do i store this images using Room db ????????
need help ...
thanks in Advance

Comment: Read about GSON and  use GSON to convert to your model and save it to your room database.

Comment: But why? Glide already handles caching if you set the cache strategy accordingly, no reason to save image in db as blobs

Comment: i tried this     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
 but when offline it doesnt shows images @EpicPandaForce

Comment: @EpicPandaForce need help of yours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966850/2413303

Comment: @EpicPandaForce   SOURCE is not found...giving suggestion as RESOURCE

Comment: @EpicPandaForce if i write preload()-->showing red/error on `.into()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce `no reason to save image in db as blobs` --> but i need to store those images in room db for further operations in offline mode

Comment: Further operations other than loading the images from URL? This is essential to the question tbh.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes...i have further task like filling the offline form so need have a db for images

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You already have the image URLs. You have them cached as files. You can load them.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how do i make db for that images which is under data table ??

Comment: BLOB. But it's bad practice.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how do i do it ???can you help??? have you seen my entity table in my question?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what query should fire in `Dao` for images(for images which is getting stored) for this `val file = File(
                                    getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                    "${System.currentTimeMillis()}${Constants.PROFILE_PIC_FILE_EXTENSION}"`

Comment: It seems you already have a solution in mind that is completely oppositional to what I've been trying to say, so I can't help you.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but this is also not working `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)` images is not getting displayed in offline mode

Answer (score 0):

Try to store it as URI. or create a type converter like this

```
class Converter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromBitmap(bmp: Bitmap): ByteArray {
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)
        return outputStream.toByteArray()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toBitmap(byteArray: ByteArray): Bitmap {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
    }
}
```

and add this type converter in you roomdb class

```
@TypeConverters(Converter::class)
abstract class RunningDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

  ///


}
```

Comment: im having a image array under data...need help entity class...do i have to make a new table ??beacuse in my data table ->image array is there ...can you please guide or edit answer

Comment: @apj123 I think you don't need any new table just save the URL of the image with its data and use Glide to display the image it will take care of caching

Comment: i dont get you @ELTEGANIMOHAMEDHAMADGABIR because `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)` doesnt work and how do i get the stored images future for my further operations??

Comment: @ELTEGANIMOHAMEDHAMADGABIR i have to fill a form offline where i need those images for that time

Comment: use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` for caching. to get ack your saved images you can select them from the table.

Comment: for glide please [visit this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230544/discussion-between-el-tegani-mohamed-hamad-gabir-and-apj123).